# what happens when i initialize again in method even though previously initialized a instance variable with same name

Tags: java

why initialization of i in method insert() makes its value 0 where as for string j (which is not initialized) prints as expected?

```
   import java.io.*;
   class Stu
   {
    int id,i;
    String name,j;
    void insert(int id,String name)
    {
     System.out.println(id+" "+name);
     int i=id;
     j=name;
    }
    void display()
    {
     System.out.println(id+" "+name);
     System.out.println(i+" "+j);
    }
  }

 class New
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Stu s1=new Stu();
  s1.insert(101,"sriram");
  s1.display();
  }
 }
```

output is:

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop>javac New.java

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop>java New

101 sriram

0 null

0 sriram

Comment: both reference are different.

Comment: The local cope hides the outer one. You can access the class variable with this.id, i.e.: this.id=id;

Comment: i suggest you read about local variables and instance variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is not initializing the same variable again in the `insert` method, but creating a new variable with same name inside the `insert` block. Your query can be summarized with scope of local variables vs global variables.

When you declare and use a variable, the compiler tries to resolve that variable in the narrowest scope available. Like, in your case, inside `insert` method, you created a variable namely, `i` which is a local variable to `insert` and its scope is till you are inside the `insert`. Once you exit that method, it goes out of scope or dies. So, you are initializing that local `i` with some value which dies once you are out of `insert`.

Now, when you ask the compiler to resolve the variable `i` inside the `display`, the compiler first looks for any `i` declared in local scope. When not found, it will search in the global scope. It then finds the `i` and prints the value.

Real life example could be::
Assume there is a guy Sriram who lives in your society. Now when somebody calls Sriram inside your house, you will prompt instantly. But, if somebody calls Sriram standing out and away from your house, the other guy will respond.

Answer (score 0):

```
void insert(int id, String name) {
            System.out.println(id + " " + name);
            **int i** = id;
            j = name;
        }
```

See, in insert function you have again declared int i.

use like  i=id;

Under, that there is huge difference between "instance variable" and "local variable".

Comment: yeah my question is,why it prints 0 while initializing i again..it doesnt make sense to me!

Comment: Do not say "initializing it again". You are declaring a completely new local variable. Local variable always override the scope of instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Due to to the scope of the program.
When you create "i" in the start of your class, that function is accessible to every function in the class; you dont declare it as anything, so its set to null.

In your insert() method, you create a new variable called i. This new i variable is on the call stack with your insert function. When that function is done being called, it "goes out of scope", and its wiped from the call stack. The variables within that function are also wiped.

When you call display, its using the "i" value you created at the beginning of the class.

Answer (score 0):

change your insert method to

```
void insert(int id,String name)
    {
     System.out.println(id+" "+name);
     i=id; // notice that i changed this line
     j=name;
    }
```

You are declaring a variable with name i in your insert method and then assigning it the value of id. as soon as the method insert finishes executing this local i variable goes out of scope.